# Preventing Numpy from Generating NaNs

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numerical code where numbers can get arbitrarily small. I am currently using `numpy.nan_to_num` to make small values `0`. Is there any way of preventing numpy from using `NaN` in the first place.

For instance, consider this situation:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.array([0]) / numpy.array([0.])
```

gives `array([ nan])`. If I then perform `numpy.nan_to_num(a)`, I get `array([ 0.])`. Is there any way of bypassing the manual `nan_to_num` step and having `numpy`  not use `NaN`s?

**I do wish to point out that in my code, I don't divide 0 by 0. There are some steps which generate NaNs (think of a root finding application with one root being 0) but I can't create a MCVE to replicate that without giving a ton of code.**

This is important because I want to prevent weird-underflow problems

Comment: I don't think you understand why 0/0 is NaN. It's not an underflow condition. You ought to ask yourself why you are dividing by zero in the first place.

Comment: One way to prevent Numpy from Generating NaNs is to write proper code and check inputs before performing operations that can generate NaN.

Comment: @Paul, David, see update.

Comment: I still don't think you fully grasp this. You seem to be intent on sweeping this under the carpet. That you won't show us how you come to have these NaNs suggests that you don't think that is important. In my experience that is unlikely to be the case.

Comment: NaN exists only in floating math.  If you use integers, there will be no NaNs.

Comment: Embrace the NaNs and find a proper way to deal with them; for example, use masked arrays, defined by the NaNs.

Comment: "I have a numerical code where numbers can get arbitrarily small.": I would say this is the actual problem. You run into machine precision (and get NaNs), or you have to find another way to deal with these small numbers (e.g., reformulate your problem in that regime) and avoid them altogether.

Comment: "This is important because I want to prevent weird-underflow problems" - this won't stop your weird underflow problems any more than disabling exceptions will fix your bugs. Underflow isn't that easy to solve.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have the very simple following Numpy example,

```
In [0]: import numpy as np
   ...: 
   ...: x_in = np.arange(1000, 1003, 1.0)
   ...: 
   ...: def f(x):
   ...:     return np.exp(2*x+1)/np.exp(3*x-2)
   ...: f(x_in)
Out[0]: array([ nan,  nan,  nan])
```

where the function `f` performs some calculations and returns NaNs for an input vector `x_in`.

There could be multiple ways of dealing with this issue.

1. By default, numpy uses 64 bit floating point numbers. In this particular case, simply casting up the input vector to 128 bit will solve the problem,

   ```
   In [1]: f(x_in.astype('float128'))
   Out[1]: array([ 1.0195336e-433,  3.7506545e-434,  1.3797887e-434], dtype=float128)
   ```

   at a price of some additional computational cost.
2. The correct way would be to consider why the NaN occur, and to rewrite the function to avoid it with 64 bit floats,

   ```
   In [2]: def f(x):
      ...:     # using the fact that exp(a)/exp(b) = exp(a-b)                  
      ...:     return np.exp((2*x-1) - (3*x-2))  
      ...: f(x_in)
      ...: 
   Out[2]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
   ```
3. Finally, in the very rare cases when we can't (or don't want to) rewrite the mathematical problem, we can use arbitrary precision floats with [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/),

   ```
   In [3]: import mpmath as mp
      ...: 
      ...: def f(x):
      ...:     mpexp_vect = np.frompyfunc(mp.exp, 1, 1)
      ...:     res = mpexp_vect(2*x+1)/mpexp_vect(3*x-2)
      ...:     return res
      ...: f(x_in)
      ...: 
   Out[3]: array([mpf('1.0195335985731257e-433'), mpf('3.7506545049859113e-434'), 
           mpf('1.3797886833213697e-434')], dtype=object)
   ```

   the result could be converted to a regular numpy array with `res.astype('float64')`. This is going to be very slow for large array sizes though.

In any case, you need to know which part of the code generates NaNs, in order to do something about it.

BTW, using `numpy.nan_to_num` to replace NaN with `0.0` is fundamentally wrong, unless you know exactly why these NaNs happen. Since NaN could be any number, and it doesn't have to be 0. For instance,
    `np.exp(-1000 + 1)/np.exp(-1000-1)` will result in a NaN with 64 bit floats, while the correct answer is `np.exp(2)` = `7.389`.